# Is there a eCommerce plugin for Pyro CMS?

Tags: codeigniter, e-commerce, pyrocms

*Im starting to use PyroCMS and Codeignigter more often;
I find it a very powerfull little CMS. However I cant find any eCommerce plugins/Shopping cart features around.*

**Question**
Does anyone know if there is a Shopping Cart plugin available for PyroCMS, or do I have to write my own?

**EXTRA:**
If I have to write my own, is there a good light PHP opensource cart that can be converted into a Pyro Addon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a plugin in development called [PyroCart](http://www.pyrocart.net/).

Comment: pitty theres nothing available now, but I can wait.

Comment: It's going to be a matter of days or weeks, but certainly quicker than writing you own :)

Answer (score 2):

[FireSALE](https://github.com/firesale/FireSALE) is also in alpha/beta and looked promising when I tried it a few weeks ago (products, categories, shipping, invoices and pluggable payment gateways).

Answer (score 0):

check [GoCart](https://github.com/gocart/GoCart). It is a CodeIgniter Based ECommerce.  You can easily adapt it to fit with Pyro CMS